# linebreak before php included file

Tags: php, html, include

I get a strange looking linebreak when including book.php:

```
echo'<div id="list-book">';
//here's where the linebreak appears
include('book.php');
echo'</div>';
```

In FF firebug the linebreak is visible and when clicking pressing backspace it dissapears and in source code it does not show at all `<div id="list-book"><table id="table-book" class="list" cellspacing="0">` (if that info helps). I also tried this which also gives a strange linebreak but that looks like 4 tabs (in FF firebug):

```
<div id="list-book">
     //here's where the linebreak appears
    <?php include('book.php'); ?>
</div>
```

book.php starts like this:

```
<?php

//include
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/config.php');
```

`...`

and the first output is:

```
echo'<table id="table" class="list" cellspacing="0">'
```

Strange (to me at least :)) is that when the book.php gets updated via js ajax load that populate the `<div id="list-book">`the linebreak disappears.

Comment: does this affect the use of the code. or is it just a source code display thing?

Comment: Maybe book.php has a [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark).

Comment: @Neal Not sure what you mean. In the browser it shows as a regular linebreak which puts a white space between the `<div>` and the `<table>` in `books.php`. It dissapears and shows correctly when the js ajax populates the `<div>`with the same script (`books.php`)

Comment: @Kay I have saved it without BOM and the fact that the linebreaks dissapear when the js ajax has reloaded the script should exclude that

Comment: Solved with `table{margin:0;border:0;padding:0;}`

Answer (score 0):

You could always call/abuse the "header" function to generate an error telling you where output was first started.